# Using beautiful soup beyond </html>

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

Is there a possibility to use beautiful soup beyond the  tag . A case in point would be the following page

```
http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/biswas-bangala_query.py?page=1
```

which has data after the end of html tag .

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you can either use [`html.parser` or`html5lib`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use) for this particular page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/biswas-bangala_query.py?page=1")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
# soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html5lib")
```

`lxml` parser does not handle this page well and it is parsed only partially.